# Why is SSL considered secure?

Tags: ssl, browser, ssl-certificate

Isn't it possible to simply capture the key while it's being negotiated between machines?

Let's say I connect to my bank's website. Browser will send request to bank server. Bank server will send me copy of its SSL certificate. If it's valid, browser will send signed ack. Isn't it possible to simply capture private key at that time?

Comment: should this perhaps by in the IT Security stackexchange, to get a better answer?

Comment: SSL is based on asymmetric encryption; public key is the one used for decryption. Private is key not sent over the network or revealed in any fashion whatsoever; that's what makes it private.

Comment: Then why can't any other machine decrypt the information using the same public key?

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was wrong: decryption --> encryption. If you want to the encrypt the message so that only server understands it, then you encrypt it by its public key. Then, the message can be decrypted only by the private key, and the server is the only one who has it. Sorry again :)

Comment: ah! It makes sense now! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @bellpeace SSL is not based on asymmetric encryption. It is based on  authentication via certificates, and then symmetric encryption using a negotiated session key.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I remember, it uses some asymmetric encryption (usually RSA) for establishing a session key. Certificate contains the info about the public key, issuers, algorithms, etc.

Comment: The key is never transfered; it's only used to sign messages.  You'd better start of reading how shared keys work in wikipedia. Also, this is offtopic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your private key (and bank's too) is never sent over the network. The bank's **public** key is a part of the X509 certificate that it sends to your browser. If banks signs anything it does it using its private key, and your browser verifies the signature using the bank's public key (from the certificate). The whole SSL session is encrypted using **symmetric** cipher (for performance reasons). To be able to do that both parties need to exchange the session key (different for each connection and renegotiated after defined interval of time). This exchange is done using **Diffie-Hellman** algorithm. During this exchange the key is not sent over the network, it is computed independently by both parties.

Comment: It's not just DH, you can also have RSA authenticated key exchange: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4346#appendix-F.1.1

Comment: True, RSA can also be used. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that the DH most popular.

Comment: I don't have any stats to back this, but you're probably right. I'd say EDH/DHE (the ephemeral variant of DH) is quite common nowadays too, and it can also provide perfect forward secrecy (i.e. even with the server's private key, you can't decrypt sniffed traffic).

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't it possible to simply capture the key while it's being
>   negotiated between machines?

No because it is never sent, it is computed independently. You would need the server's private key, which is private, to repeat the independent computations that lead to the session key. So it is secure.

Comment: Can you please tell how it is done, from the point server sends its certificate to the point where key is negotiated, i.e SSL connection is established.

Comment: No I can't, it takes several pages of RFC 2246.

Comment: @EndofFile: there are also various tutorials describing how SSL/TLS works, for example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLOverview) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783349%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Only public key is shared. The bank dosen't need to share the private one.

Comment: I hope not to mess with others things but I think it works this way: Your machine encrypt with the server public key, and only the server's private key can decrypt it. And so i think you should have a key pair too, so the server can encrypt messages to send you.

Comment: Ah you've landed on an interesting issue - there are in fact two different versions of SSL (which is actually TLS nowadays). The one, most commonly used, is "non-mutual" SSL. In this, you have a certified public key from the bank, but the bank has nothing from you. Thus you can send data with confidentiality to the bank, but the bank can't send data to you. The other is Mutual SSL, which you can read with its related issues about here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication. The key is that most web apps are designed to only need one-way security.

Comment: Well, this was what I remember from the class about certificates I had some time ago. Was not sure if SSL works the same way

Comment: @mfranki Your statement about 'two different versions of SSL' is not correct. SSL/TLS can be either mutually or singly *authenticated*. Mutual authentication doesn't constitute a different 'version'. Both authentication modes are secure in both directions; the only difference is that in mutual authentication, both peers have proof of the other's identity. The Wikipedia article you cited is not without its errors as well.

Comment: @ismaelga No. A symmetric session key is negotiated and used for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Private key is not shared and is not stored in the cert.